# What's mean a compact and discriminative descriptor ?

Tags: image, image-processing, sift, surf, feature-extraction

I read in an article

`Both SIFT and SURF descriptors show good discriminating properties. However, they are
not compact.`

what's the meaning of discrimination and compactness here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give an example.

Assume, I have a phone. If I tell you, it is by COMPANY1, you could recognize it from phones made by other companies. Through, you could not recognize it from all COMPANY1 phones.
So this descriptor is not discriminant enough.

If I tell you, it is is COMPANY1 and MODEL 5S, you could recognize from much more phones.
So it is discriminant descriptor, but not compact.

If I compress COMPANY1 MODEL 5S to just number (number in sorted list of all phones of all companies), let say 53 - this descriptor is both compact and discriminative.